# last-child() and :after not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, css

Hello friends following is my code

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu-item">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.clear-right{
color:red;
}
.menu-item:last-child{
    color:red;}
.menu-item:last-child:after
    {
content:'hi';
}
```

my code is working perfectly in  all browser but not working in IE m trying to do same thng using jquery

```
$(".menu-item li:last-child:after").css('content','"hi"');
```

you can check [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/PBAas/59/)
but its also not working please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just append another li using jquery? Or just append any content period. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:after` and `:before` are pseudo elements, which cannot be manipulated afterwards. So you can't do this.

An alternate possible selector would be this

```
$(".menu-item li").last().css('content', 'hi');
```

---

***One trick to solve it is.***

Create a class with your needed CSS

```
.newClass {}
.newClass:after { content: 'hi'; }
```

Now using jQuery switch them.

```
$(".menu-item li").last().addClass("newClass");
```

Comment: i know @Strax.. any other way to do this

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `:after` pseudo selector in jQuery, since the element doesn't actually exist in the DOM. It works in your example because it's set in the CSS, if you remove that rule it won't work anymore. The problem with IE is that pseudo selectors are not fully supported and buggy.

Comment: yes i know .. i use `:aftter` in jquery bcz i want to show that what i want to do

Comment: yeah, but but you want to do is NOT possible. You can't select a pseudo element in jQuery because it isn't an element and it's not in the DOM.

Comment: thank for your help @elclanrs . is there any other way to do the same